# Could not parse my XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I tried to parse this using lots of way I found but could't parse this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<iBridge xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<User ID="162715" TOKEN="ABE02FD9-89FA-47F4-B687-E75D7AB63F4B" USER_COOKIE="ASP.NET_SessionId=g2b3pl453rmbatjpsitjz255|Login=|Login=8D34CBFE9FD0108D506BD78D42E76CB0B424FB1335DA48E8AA52D11466BAC8EE55FABB019D1C81E6A7E91A62E47C3DE049CB9C3BFBC680F50208282F8BA2451C2202585E49D62F1A" FULL_NAME="Sachin Kumar" FIRST_NAME="Sachin" LAST_NAME="Kumar" COMPANY="Unikove" LAST_FIRST="KUMAR, SACHIN" ADDRESS_1="Address One" ADDRESS_2="" CITY="My City" STATE_PROVINCE="AE" ZIP="90001" COUNTRY="" PREFERRED_MAIL="1" PREFERRED_BILL="1" CO_ID="" MEMBER_TYPE="WEB" MEMBER_TYPE_DESCRIPTION="Web Sign-Up" EMAIL="sachin.kumar@unikove.com" ASSIGNMENT="" />
</iBridge>
```

Comment: Please post your code for better understand.,

Comment: what are you trying to parse anyways?

Answer (score 0):

if you save your xml file in the root of your php script and call it my_xml.xml , the php script would be :

```
<?php
    $iBridge = simplexml_load_file('my_xml.xml');
    foreach ($iBridge as $userinfo){
        $id = $userinfo['ID'];
        $token = $userinfo['TOKEN'];
        $user_cookie = $userinfo['USER_COOKIE'];

        echo "ID: '".$id."<br/>TOKEN: ".$token."<br/>USER COOKIE: ".$user_cookie."<br/>";
        }

?>
```

You can add the rest of properties yourself just like the pattern above, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,etc..

Comment: Ardy actually i am calling a service which gives me dynamic xml so i need to parse this xml content without saving.

Comment: then instead of 'my_xml.xml' put in the direct URL of the service.

Comment: Ardy did you try to parse this xml i have given in my question. i tried but could not.

Comment: Yes Kumar, if you save the php script in the same directory as your xml file, you will see the three properties printed out.